# Calling a stored procedure in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

My question is

Calling a stored proc within a stored proc within another stored proc. 
When is this type of development detrimental?

In order to promote code reusablity we have encapsulated various insert/update statements into stored procedures. So if want to insert A Foo record then you would pass the parameters to the CreateFoo stored proc and go about your day.

Well lets assume a **Foo** object needs to Create A **Bar** objects which also Creates a **Mark** object.

Thus your stored proc will call the **foo** stored proc which will then call the **bar** stored proc which will then call the **mark** stored proc.

When is this not a good idea, and what are my other options. Thank you very much.
If you could, could you put the sources that back up your answer. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Do you only ever insert one row at a time?

Comment: Yes. When call **FOO** I do, but if i didnt and the stored procedures had to do a plethora of things when would it actually have an negative affect. Are you saying if i am just inserting 1 row i should just duplicate that insert statement everywhere i am using it instead of calling a stored proc?

Comment: So how would you insert `10000` `foo` rows? You would call the procedure in a loop 10,000 times?

Comment: We haven't planned out what we will do for mass updates like that. I figure we would do some sort of ssis package. For now we are dealing with at max 20 **foo** record inserts which they themselves would call **bar** and **mark** 20 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not good or bad - if you need to call the one procedure from the another, just do it.

Implementing logic on database level in stored procedures is not a good way of doing things in most of the cases:

- it makes your application depends on this particular DBMS
- it is more complex to scale the application on database layer then to scale it on the middle layer.
- it complicates debugging (unless you can place a breakpoint in your SP)
- SP language (SQL) usually is not flexible and powerful as middle layer language

But for some applications (and it may be your case) it is better to use SP - when the cons are beaten by the pros: simple and quick implementation of the logic on the language you know better.

Comment: I believe I have miscommunicated something.This is in essence what I would like to accomplish.We have a Witness record, this witness record contains a personID which is the primary key of a person table. This table contains all the information pertaining to that person. We want to insert the person record first then take the scope identity and place that in the witness record. We want to be able to have a generic sp which inserts people so we  do not have to duplicate the person recod insertion again

Comment: @gh9 - That makes sense. It doesn't lend itself to set based processing though so I might be tempted to use the `OUTPUT` clause instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `Table Valued Parameters` rather than scalar parameters to allow for the possibility of dealing with multirow inserts in a more set based way.

Comment: Sql Server 2005, no table valued parameters. Why would the output clause be better then a return statement?

Comment: @gh9 - [`OUTPUT clause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) not `OUTPUT` parameters.